# Missing from-clause entry for table / undefined table error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, pg

This works locally in SQLite, however when I push to heroku I get this issue.

This issue only occurs when I end the statement in ORDER BY, otherwise it doesn't give me an issue. It's like it breaks conversations into two conversations and then confuses the two, I don't remember this error happening earlier--I could have sworn it was working.

Sorry this is so convoluted...

```
SELECT distinct conversations.*, receipts.is_read, profiles.nickname 
FROM conversations INNER JOIN notifications 
ON notifications.conversation_id = conversations.id 
INNER JOIN receipts ON receipts.notification_id = notifications.id 
INNER JOIN profiles ON profiles.id = notifications.sender_id 
WHERE (receipts.mailbox_type = 'inbox' AND ((receipts.receiver_id = #{self.id})))
  UNION
SELECT distinct conversations.*, receipts.is_read, profiles.nickname 
FROM conversations INNER JOIN notifications 
ON notifications.conversation_id = conversations.id 
INNER JOIN receipts ON receipts.notification_id = notifications.id 
INNER JOIN profiles on profiles.id = notifications.sender_id 
WHERE (receipts.mailbox_type = 'sentbox' AND ((receipts.receiver_id = #{self.id}))) 
ORDER BY conversations.updated_at desc
```

However Heroku logs show this error.

```
2014-07-03T09:59:12.485350+00:00 app[web.1]: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "conversations"
2014-07-03T09:59:12.761705+00:00 app[web.1]: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "conversations"
```

http://pastebin.com/eNkBdkYR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just did the query without union and it works!
It wasn't working earlier because the result set it returned looked different for some reaosn.